# Is where a way to track data changes in SQL SERVER 2000?

Tags: sql-server, logging, sql-server-2000, ssms, tracking

For example, if I execute an UPDATE/INSERT query to change values in a table, can it be tracked on SQL2000?

Answer (score 2):

No. Well, yes, if you consider writing your own tracking triggers and / or analysing the logfile to be tracking.

CDC - Change Data Capture - was introduces WAAAAAAAYYYY later than SQL Server 2000... which is ancient and seriously out of support, btw.